# How to print char[] to a messagebox?

Tags: visual-c++

I want to print `str2` to messagebox, but nothing was printed. Here is the code..

```
    char str2[256];
    fstream file_op2("C:\\PROGRA~1\\executables\\path.txt",ios::in);
    file_op2.getline(str2, 256);
    file_op2.close();  

    CString mycustompath;
    mycustompath = str2;
    MessageBox(NULL,mycustompath.GetBuffer() , L"read custom path", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: [A printf type of MessageBox function which takes variable arguments](http://ntcoder.com/bab/2007/05/24/a-printf-type-of-messagebox-function-which-takes-variable-arguments/)